# Shopware 6 Plugin Custom config

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I am developing a plugin in shopware 6 and for the configuration view of the plugin I am using the config.xml

I need to add some dynamic behavior that depends on configuration values so I wanted to know if i can make my own config without having to use the config.xml

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the word "dynamic" config? If possible try to give an example of a code snippet so that people can understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to show o dont a input depends on previus save values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `config.xml` is a convenience feature. As such for its ease of use it comes with some limitations. However nothing is keeping you from [adding custom entities](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/add-custom-complex-data) and managing them to your liking with your own [custom administration modules](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/administration/add-custom-module).

As a sort of middle ground you can also add [custom config fields](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/add-plugin-configuration#advanced-custom-input-fields) in the `config.xml`. This will allow you to use a specific component, which could also be a custom component introduced by you, for handling inputs and storing of the data.

```xml
<component name="my-custom-component">
   <name>My Custom Component</name>
</component>
```

```js
Shopware.Component.register('my-custom-component', {
    template,

    props: {
        value: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: '',
        },
    },

    data() {
        return {
            currentValue: this.value,
        };
    },

    watch: {
        value(value) {
            this.currentValue = value;
        },
    },

    methods: {
        onChange(event) {
            this.$emit('change', this.currentValue);
        },
    },
});
```

```html
<sw-text-field
    :value="currentValue"
    @change="onChange"
/>
```